# How to enhance existing Bluetooth antenna on audio device (Pro-Ject BT Box E)?

Tags: audio, antenna, bluetooth

I recently got a Pro-Ject BT Box E which is a BT receiver and DAC that sends the sound to an audio amplifier. The problem is that the range is so lame (less than 2m for undisrupted listening.)

I've opened the box to check if there was a connection for an external antenna, but I didn't find any info on the IC I see on the circuit and I don't have knowledge of Bluetooth.

I've included 2 pictures of the PCB.

- Can I use one of the five "free" pins to connect an antenna?
- Can I just solder another antenna on the existing one?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Pro-Ject is a serious brand; if you can show 2 m is sub-par and that the problem isn't with your BT sender, I would contact them or your supplier and query them.

Comment: Ocrdu is right, 2m is ridiculous. Perhaps the unit is damaged or there is something wrong with 'the other end'. Try asking the seller for a replacement before tinkering on your own. Just don't show the service desk the picture you posted here ;)

Comment: Hi, I think everything is ok on the other side, since any other BT device have an acceptable range with it (namely other BT speakers). I will contact the seller

Answer (score 1):

[image]

[*Instructions for use*](https://www.project-audio.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/BTBoxE9V-Manual.pdf)

According to the technical specifications attached, the effective range of the wireless signal is up to 10m in the case of direct visibility.

There is no facility for an external antenna.

There may be a problem either with your Android device or your Pro-Ject BT Box E.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, I will contact the seller

Answer (score 0):

That might be possible in theory. But it will be difficult, if done incorrectly it will worsen the situation and lets be real: its not worth your time.

For your first question: no, you cant use the other 'free' pins, because they are not used for antenna purposes. Where you see the antenna trace leaving the module (3dr from the bottom right), that's where you need to be. The pins above and below that are very likely ground pins, as you can see they are connected to the copper plane on the top. The other three pins on that end do not seem directly connected to anything perhaps they just are not used.

The small rectangular chip component after that is used for something called ' matching'. Long story short, it's a very carefully tuned (selected) component to work specifically in tandem with the antenna in this product to ensure the Bluetooth RF signal is transferred to the antenna in an optimal manner. The antenna that is in turn connected to this is designed and tuned even more carefully to make sure the BL signal radiates properly. Its a very carefully balanced mix of components.

So for your second question: no, just soldering an antenna (whatever kind you might come up with) on top of the existing one will throw off this carefully designed system and make the situation even worse.

If you ever want to attempt this (I do not recommend), remove the series matching component, cut the trace to the shunt matching component, hope that the RF output port is matched to 50 ohms on the module and stick a dipole antenna on the RF port. That should be close enough in terms of impedance to get at least something going. But that is a crude solution to say the least.

Just return the unit! Bluetooth should be able to reach an order of magnitude more than what you are getting.
Also just a thought, there aren't any significant (metal) obstructions between the devices? If it is currently tucked away in-between some metal amplifier casings, try to bring it out in the open some more.

Comment: Thanks for the info. No, no obstacle between the device and my phone, it's just next to the left speaker which is made of wood and a shelf, also made of wood